# DeepLab v3 citiscapes label order (mobilenetv2_coco_cityscapes_trainfine)

Tags: tensorflow, label

I am trying to use the mobilenetv2_coco_cityscapes_trainfine model (deeplab v3) to label some images. Unfortunately I cannot find the fitting label order. I am more or less following the https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/deeplab_demo.ipynb example.)

To use the results I need an array with the correct order of the labelnames. (car, motorcycle... etc...)

So far I tried the order as in:
https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/dataset-overview/
(road, sidewalk, parking, rail track, person, rider...)

But then segmentation doesn't fit the images. (Road is correctly detected but other labels seem to be shifted by 1. (e.g. cars are labeled as bicycles.)

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!